# After upgrade Flutter 3.0 can't run iOS xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

After upgrading to Flutter 3.0 I am facing this problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because you Xcode cache, clean all cache and rebuild it work: [Clear Xcode cache](https://macpaw.com/how-to/clear-xcode-cache)